# Is there a way to see the custom firebase events that are fired from an apk and the parameter values

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to see which firebase events are being fired and with what parameters in a third party app android native app...

Comment: can you explain whats your problem is that

Comment: So, say there is a competitor's android app xyz and I want to find all the custom events declared in that app. How can I do that

Comment: search pusher manager that help you to custom events and trigger the listerner in real time like firebase